# My Laptop Starts Heating Up Using Every Version Of Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, overheating

I Have A Dell XPSL502X , And I'm Facing Issues Using A Lot Of Hardware Resources And Not Making My Computer Melt Down, It has 8GB RAM Memory, 2GH i7 intel, and ....

Why The Hell It's acting like this...?

though i have to mention it cannot recognize my graphic card, THE ONLY variant that could recognize my graphic card so far was SABAYON on Gentoo...Anyway...if u use sth like a system hardware monitor which is the default app in gnome for monitoring being used resources like ram , hard, cpu , ... , THIS is what happens to me : suddenly cpu's rate goes to TOP and the X starts to really slow down, my laptop starts heating up, and it gets really really hot...

do u have any idea...?

Comment: Although title includes `every version of Ubuntu` it is about 12.04 and earlier which are EOL. Modern day answers may not address these versions and there is not enough details provided by OP on this unanswered question. VTC as `not reproducible`.